# Derivation of kinetic energy

Tags: classical-mechanics, integration

We know that:

$$
F_{net} \stackrel{\dot{m}=0}= m\dot{v} = m\frac{d\vec{v}}{d\vec{r}}\vec{v}
$$

$$
F_{net} \ d\vec{r} = m \vec{v} \cdot d\vec{v}
$$

$$
K.E \stackrel{\int}= \frac{1}{2}m|\vec{v}|^2
$$

My question is: How do you integrate with respect to a vector? I gave context because I might be wrong with the mathematical part.

How come $\int{\vec{v} \ d\vec{v}} = v^2/2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trivial to see if you define the vector quantity in terms of its components: $$\vec{v} = v_x \hat{{x}} + v_y \hat{{y}} + v_z \hat{{z}}.$$

The infinitesimal element $\text{d}\vec{v}$ is shorthand for $$ \text{d}\vec{v} = \text{d} v_x \hat{{x}} + \text{d} v_y \hat{{y}} + \text{d} v_z \hat{{z}}.$$

Therefore, it should be clear that $$\int \vec{v} \cdot \text{d}\vec{v} = \int \left( v_x \text{d}v_x + v_y \text{d}v_y + v_z \text{d}v_z \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left(v_x^2 + v_y^2 + v_z^2\right),$$

where in the first step I've just used the properties of the dot product: $\hat{x}\cdot\hat{x} = 1$ and $\hat{x}\cdot\hat{y}=0$ and so on, and all the quantities in the second step are scalars and so their integral should be quite obvious.

You'll recognise the right-hand-side to just be the "length" (or modulus) squared of the vector $\vec{v}$, and so you see that $$\int \vec{v} \cdot \text{d}\vec{v} = \frac{1}{2}|\vec{v}|^2$$